# How to add Swedish symbols(unicode) to my REGEX?

Tags: regex, unicode, diacritics

I got this regex:

CITY_REGEX: /^[a-zA-Z\u4e00-\u9eff\s'-.]+$/,

And I need to add Swedish language (e.g. åäöøæ ). What should I add to the regex to recognize those symbols?

I looked at this but cant seem to figure out what exactly to add
http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/bylanguage/nordic.html

Comment: ***Swedish**: `[a-zA-ZäöåÄÖÅ]`*

Answer (score 0):

Good article to go on that topic is [Unicode Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html). Shortly you have to add codes of Swedish characters to your regexp ( see more provided link).

Answer (score 0):

Regex.Escape("...") should work.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape(v=vs.110).aspx